# Apply Class on load

Tags: jquery

I want to apply the following style =`'position: relative; left: 42px;'` to the label if value of the textbox is empty. and onfocus this style has to be removed

```
<label for'13321'>Name</label><input type='text' id='13321' class='box'>
<label for'14422'>Name</label><input type='text' id='14422' class='box'>
```

Comment: So, I don't get it, are you trying to apply a class or a style?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the style into a class, say `yourClass`, and then you can use the following:

```
$(function() {
    $('input.box').filter(function() {
         return $(this).val() === "";
    })
    .prev('label')   // go to label
      .addClass('yourClass')
    .end()    // back to input
    .one('focus', function() {
         $(this).prev('label').removeClass('yourClass');
    });
});
```

or without `filter` (you have to test what is more performant):

```
 $('input.box:not([value]), input.box[value=""]')
   .prev('label')
     .addClass('yourClass')
   .end()
   .one(...
```

*Edit: I missed that you want to add the class to the label. Fixed.*

**Update:** If you want to reapply the class, in case the value stays empty, you have add a `blur` listener and use `focus` instead of `one` above:

```
.focus(function() {
    $(this).prev('label').removeClass('yourClass');
})
.blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() === "") {
        $(this).prev('label').addClass('yourClass');
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

css

```
.empty{
    position: relative; left: 42px;        
}
```

js

```
  $(function() {
      $(":input:text").each(function(){
         if( $(this).val() == "")
         {
             $(this).prev("label").addClass("empty");
             $(this).focus(function(){
                     $(this).prev("label").removeClass("empty");
                 })
         }
      });
   });
```

demo

http://jsfiddle.net/jURc9/13/

Comment: he want class to the `label` not `text`

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input.box').each(function(){
   if($(this).val()=="") {
       $(this).addClass('new-class');
   }
})
   $('input.box').focus(function(){
       $(this).removeClass('new-class')
   })
})
```

CSS:

```
.new-class {
   position: relative;
   left: 42px;
}
```

Comment: This won't work. You have to iterate over all the input elements. `if($('input.box').val()=="")` will just compare the value of the first found element.